# How do I access a share drive in a cygwin bash script?

Tags: bash, cygwin

```
#!/bin/bash
"mirror -R //thevault/Shared/Operations/Marketing/test --only-missing -e ;exit"
```

I'm using lftp to mirror a folder on a share drive. But it fails with "No such file or directory" What's the correct way to write this? and How would I escape a space in the file name. I've tried literally everything.

I've also tried `/cygdrive/s/Operations/Marketing/test`. This works while I'm logged in and I run the script. But when the task is run while I'm not logged in the log file I get the same "No such file" Error.

Comment: I think the first step to solving this problem is to use `sftp` instead of Windows networking if you need this to work while you aren't logged in.  I have seen `samba` ported to `cygwin`, but you could just as easily solve this problem with `sftp` and host key authentication

Comment: Mike, Thanks for your response. This is only a quick and dirty concept just so I can further refine the process with tools like sftp and samba. Do you have an idea how I would put the correct path?

Comment: if you use `sftp`, it's not a matter of using a path to access the server; use connect via sftp and `put` / `get` the file based on directory you setup when you installed the `sftp` server.  So you would setup the `sftp` server with access to the directory you're trying to mirror

Comment: @Kelbizzle, are changes happening on both machines or on one machine?  If changes happen on both machines, you probably will need something like `rsync` instead of just pulling files via `sftp`.  `rsync` also implies shell access via `ssh`, so it can start `rsync` on both sides of the connection

Comment: The changes happen locally on a share drive. Any files that don't exist on the server, get uploaded to the server. Anything that isn't on the the share drives get removed from the ftp server. Using lftp with --only-missing -e options work perfectly for what we need to do. 

I'll check out the solutions you mentioned. Right now I MS task scheduler running the script every ten minutes or so. It works for right now. But only when I'm logged in. The other issue is I'm not an admin for the web/ftp server. So I'm limited as to what changes I can make to this particular server without approval .

Comment: Thanks again for your response Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working perfectly while logged out.

```
#!/bin/bash
lftp ftp://username:password@server.com -e "mirror -R //thevault/Share/folder/folder/folder\ with\ spaces/folder/folder --only-missing -e;exit"
```

It was the escaped spaces in my path. The reason that this didn't work is because when I retyped the path I misspelled share. //thevault/shared <~~ incorrect

```
#!/bin/bash
"mirror -R //thevault/Shared/folder/folder/test --only-missing -e ;exit"
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that is support in general in cygwin for UNC pathnames (ie `\\server\share`) so you'll have to rely on mapping to a network drive and then using `/cygdrive/s`.  To fix the problem with it not working when you aren't logged in, you'll need to call the Windows `NET` program from your script:

```
net use s: \\thevault\Shared password /user:myuser
```

There may be some security implications to having the password in plaintext, so another possibility is to ensure that the script is running from a user account that has read permission to this server, and then you can omit the password.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I totally forgot about permissions.

Comment: I know this answer is 10 years old, but today Cygwin directly support UNC paths.  Ref: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#unc-paths